# Issue with declare references

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, build, external

I need to build a VB.net solution that calls a DLL. When I build the solution then the build fails with “Not allowed to Declare references to external procedures”.
A customized Visual Studio 10 must be used for the application.
VS19 can’t be used, VS10 must be used because it is a system pre-requisite of the vendor.
Within a class that is used in a special control system, an external DLL must be used that contains very special function that are essential for the intended function.
The following code snippet demonstrates the call. The snippet uses the windows function “GetSystemTime” for demonstration purposes only. The real application uses another DLL.

```
Imports Custom.BlockBase

Imports System

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Structure SYSTIME
    Public wYear As Short
    Public wMonth As Short
    Public wDayOfWeek As Short
    Public wDay As Short
    Public wHour As Short
    Public wMinute As Short
    Public wSecond As Short
    Public wMillisecond As Short
End Structure

Public Class clsLOADDlls

    <DllImport("kernel32", entrypoint:="GetSystemTime", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Sub GetSystemTime(ByRef _lpSystemTime As SYSTIME)

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Block

    Inherits BlockBase

    Public Overrides Sub Execute()

        Dim objSysTime As SYSTIME

        Dim intTime As Integer

        ' --- load time
        Call clsLOADDlls.GetSystemTime(objSysTime)

        intTime = CInt((objSysTime.wMinute * 60) + objSysTime.wSecond)

    End Sub

End Class
```

My guess is that there is a switch to suppress the afore-mentioned build error, but I failed to find it. Maybe somebody got a hint for me?

Comment: I can sort of see why a customer might want code compiled by a certain compiler but why should they care what IDE you used. You could write your code in notepad.  I don't believe that VS10 is supported anymore.

Comment: Instead of DLLImport try Delcare statement like; Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" (ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Comment: I replaced the declare statement with " Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" (ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)" but the build error still occurs.